# SharePoint Online: Issues when try to connect to .Net Core API secured with Azure AD using AadHttpClient from SharePoint app

Tags: rest, azure-active-directory, sharepoint-online

SPFx |
SharePoint Online

---

Hello,
I have a custom .Net core API uploaded to Azure. I need to connect the secure Azure AD API with the SharePoint client-side web parts (using SharePoint framework v 1.7). To connect to Azure AD I use AadHttpClient.

I receive the following error when opening API management page:
**[HTTP]:500 - [CorrelationId] {} [Version]:16.0.0.8713 - Unknown Error**
I see in the development tool that the error comes from: 
Request URL: /_api/SPOInternalUseOnly.SPOWebAppServicePrincipal/PermissionGrants

I'm a global administrator.

When I try to approve the permission request it shows an error:
**[HTTP]:400 - [CorrelationId] {}: [Version]:16.0.0.8713 - The service principal for permssion request {projectName}-client-side-solution could not be found.**

I try to approve it via Azure powershell **Approve-SPOTenantServicePrincipalPermissionRequest** but I receive the exactly the same error.

package-solution.json contains:

```
"webApiPermissionRequests": [
  {
    "resource": "{displayName of the registered app}",
    "scope": "user_impersonation"
  } 
]
```

In Azure app service settings -> Authentication/Authorization -> Active Directory Authentication --> App Service Authentication is On -> Express -> Use Existing App.

When I execute this I see my service registered there:
az ad sp list --query "sort_by([*].{displayName: displayName, objectId: objectId}, &displayName)" -o table

I also try to execute Enable-SPOTenantServicePrincipal but receive an error again : Unknown Error

Do you have any ideas?